# Add line break in print statement in R

Tags: r

When using the print function to print to the screen, I would like one line to appear on one line, and the next line to be on a second line.

with this line

```
print( 
    paste( 
        "hey I want this to be line one", "and this to be line two", "would be great if you could help"
    )
)
```

I want this to print

[1] "hey I want this to be line one

[2] and this to be line two would be great if you could help"

Comment: You could use `c()` instead of `paste()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume your sample output should actually be three lines instead of two... You should use `cat` instead of `print`, and add `sep="\n"` to the `paste` statement:

```
 cat(paste("hey I want this to be line one", 
           "and this to be line two", 
           "would be great if you could help" ,sep="\n"))
```

Output:

```
hey I want this to be line one
and this to be line two
would be great if you could help
```